# grep match a concat of variable and string (dash) in piped input

Tags: bash, awk, grep

(NOTE: this is a bash question, not k8s)

I have a working script which will fetch the name

```
admin-job-0
```

from a list of kubernetes cronjobs, of which there can be up to 32 ie. `admin-job-0 -1, -2, -3 ... -31`

**Question**: How do I `grep "-$1$"` ie a dash, the number, and no more, instead of just the number as I have below?

**Bonus question**: Is there any way to do what I'm doing below without the `if/else` logic regardless of whether there's an argument passed?

```bash
fetch-admin-job() {
  if [[ -n $1 ]]; then
    name=$(kubectl get cronjob | awk '/^admin-job.*/{print $1}' | grep $1 )
  else
    # get the first one (if any)
    name=$(kubectl get cronjob | awk '/^admin-job.*/{print $1}')
  fi
  echo $name
}

#example:
fetch-admin-job 0
```

Comment: Could you please show what is your expected output in your question, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: what happens when you try running `grep "-$1$"`? I'm guessing you get a syntax error and if so ... for many commands an argument of `--` will disable the interpretation of special characters in arguments that come after the `--`; `grep "-1$"` will try to interpret the `-1` as a flag to `grep` while `grep -- "-1$"` will treat the `-1` as a literal string to be pattern matched; net result: try `grep -- "-$1$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass to grep a double-hyphen (`--`), this signals the end of the option and a dash at the start of the pattern does not harm,  i.e.

```
grep -- "$1"
```

or

```
grep -- "$1$"
```

or whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: I accepted this answer because not every future user will be dealing with `awk` but the answer by @anubhava is still very helpful for compact programming purposes.

Comment: @OliverWilliams : I have not included the final `$` in my first solution, since you also didn't have it in the code you posted; however you mentioned it in your question. Therefore it was not clear to me whether or not you wanted your pattern to be anchored at the end of the line. Actually, since the pattern comes as from outside the script (as parameter), I would not implicitly anchor the pattern anywhere, but leave this decision to the caller of your script.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your function code with this:

```bash
fetch-admin-job() {
   kubectl get cronjob |
   awk -v n="$1" '!n || $1 == "admin-job-" n {print $1}'
}
```

Then invoke it as:

```bash
fetch-admin-job 0
fetch-admin-job 4
fetch-admin-job
```

We are using this condition in `awk`:

- `!n`: will be true when you don't pass anything in first argument
- `||`: OR
- `$1 == "admin-job-" n`: Will be used to compare first column in output of `kubectl` command with first argument you pass. Note that this is equivalent of `awk '/^admin-job/ ...' | grep "-$1$"`.
- **You don't need to use `grep` on an `awk` output as `awk` can handle that part as well.**